# webaii: clicking an <i> element

Tags: webaii

I am using webaii to write some test automation, and can't figure out how to Click() an < i> element.

They seem to define the Click() method for Control elements, and < i> is not defined as a Control element.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the Browser.Actions.Click() method to click the element.

Those elements that webaii does not wrap up in classes (which have the methods you need), can still have these actions applied via the Actions class. The framework arranges for the actions to be applied via Javascript.